# Django ASGI and WSGI Deploying Together

Tags: python, django, wsgi, asgi

The application I developed using Django includes WSGI and ASGI applications together. What kind of way do I need to follow while deploying this application? In general, when I searched on the internet, I could not find anythig that deployed WSGI and ASGI applications together. what is a way to accomplish this?

Comment: For WSGI you can use this code while deploying

"""
WSGI config for your project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()


and for ASGI you can follow this link 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/asgi/

Answer (score 1):

I do this by putting nginx in front and routing requests to the appropriate server.  I'm assuming you likely have a wsgi django application, and a asgi websocket or something like that.

In that case, you run the wsgi app on one port, and the asgi app on another, and nginx on 80/443 and let it handle routing to the right place based on the URL path.